# xcode: redirect to setting/about directly (URL scheme) in iOS11

Tags: swift, xcode, ios11

I'm trying to make a button that enables to redirect to setting/about page (that shows IMEI).

It seems like older ver iOS (like iOS8?) allowed this but current iOS doesnt work. By below,

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=General&path=About")!)
```

It just goes to setting page (not setting/about page). Do you know any ways to do this in iOS11?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this in iOS 11. The best you can do to open any Settings is open the settings page for your own app, using

```
  UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!, completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gereon.. Hard to prove something is impossible :-)